# How to use PrtSc key as modifier (AltGr) key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, layout

I like to **set the AltGr key to Ctrl** so I can have the Ctrl key under my right thumb. Also, I **set the key at the right of AltGr to AltGr**, so I can still use it to insert tildes and other Spanish and Catalan letters. The thing is that on my last keyboard, this key was the Windows key, so I just used this command and it all worked fine:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -model pc105 -variant altgr-intl -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl -option lv3:rwin_switch
```

Lv3 is the name of the AltGr keymap, I guess.

But on my new keyboard, **the key at the right of AltGr is PrtSc**, and looking at the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst file:

```
  lv3                  Key to choose the 3rd level
  lv3:switch           Right Ctrl
  lv3:menu_switch      Menu
  lv3:win_switch       Any Win
  lv3:lwin_switch      Left Win
  lv3:rwin_switch      Right Win
  lv3:alt_switch       Any Alt
  lv3:lalt_switch      Left Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch      Right Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch_multikey Right Alt; Shift+Right Alt as Compose
  lv3:ralt_alt         Right Alt never chooses 3rd level
  lv3:enter_switch     Enter on keypad
  lv3:caps_switch      Caps Lock
  lv3:bksl_switch      Backslash
  lv3:lsgt_switch      &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  lv3:caps_switch_latch Caps Lock; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level chooser
  lv3:bksl_switch_latch Backslash; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd level chooser
  lv3:lsgt_switch_latch &lt;Less/Greater&gt;; acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd level chooser
```

It seems like PrtSc can't be set to AltGr (lv3). Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 78 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

This maps the lvl3 shift to the keycode 78. On my system the print-screen button registers as keycode 78.

If for some reason this doesn't work for you.
Check the keycode for print-screen on your system.
Use this command:

```
xev -event keyboard
```

It creates a window. If you press a key while that window is focused, it prints key info into the terminal. The keycode of the pressed key is inside that info text.  Press print-screen while that window is focued and find its keycode in the terminal.

If the keycode is X instead of 78 on your system.
Just swap X for the 78 in the first command.

To make the changes permanent, put the first command into your startup config, whatever that may be. Judging from the question you probably know where it is.

Alternatively you can define a custom keyboard layout. For that see the second link.

Links to check out:

https://lukaszzagroba.com/creating-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-linux/
http://karols.github.io/blog/2013/11/18/creating-custom-keyboard-layouts-for-linux/